# Trigger mouse event when pointer is X units away from bottom of browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

Ok, my question is simple, though I am unsure if the answer will be. I have an element that is fixed to the bottom of the browser window. When it is unneeded I want to hide it(set height to 0px). When the user's mouse is X units away from the bottom of the WINDOW (not document) I want to show the div again. I googled a bit and all I could find was information on triggering events/preforming actions when the page was scrolled to X units away from the bottom. I need not the exact code of how to do this, if I could just be pointed into the right direction.

The question(for those that didn't see it):
How to fire an event/execute a function when the mouse pointer is within X units from the bottom of the browser window(not document)?

A few notes:
This is for a greasemonkey/userscript so answers need not apply to IE.
Please do not suggest the usage of a library. For something as small as this, requiring an entire library is not an answer I am willing to accept.

**ANSWER:**
Building off of Kir lvlev's answer below(Remember to give his answer an upvote):

```
// Standards compliant browsers
// if you have an IE solution, post it in the comments and I will add it.
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
    // 20 is the number of pixels from the bottom inwhich the action should be preformed
    if ((this.innerHeight - 20) <= e.clientY) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: You could try putting an empty div (with width/height set) and add an on hover listener to it. That way when the user scrolls over that section of the screen it launches your javascript function

Comment: The problem with that is the div consumes mouse events, such as clicks on items that the div is covering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use mousemove event handler

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e)
{
      //mouse coordinates: e.pageX e.pageY
      //window height $(window).height()
});
```

non-jquery:

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  //e.clientX e.clientY
  //window.innerHeight
}
```

Comment: I rewrote my answer. This is much better

Comment: It's also jquery. I asked for non-library dependant answers. Also, that's for the document. not the browser window

Comment: Building off of your answer:

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
 // 20 is the number of units from the bottom inwhich the action should be preformed
 if ((window.innerHeight - 20) <= e.clientY) {
  //do stuff
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

check out this jsfiddle I made for you: j sfiddle.net/Cnhvm/

The general idea is demonstrated there. You would obviously want to relocate the div, change its size, and remove the background color. Also make sure the z-index value it has places it on top of any other content in your page.

This is standard javascript: `onmouseover="hoverOver();"`

If you want to preserve your links you can put them in some small blocks over the div with more work.

Comment: The issue here is first, this is a userscript, meaning I have no control of the HTML. The second issue is the page is longer than the window. Meaning that each time the page scrolls, I'll have to add/remove items from the div and place them back into their specific place in to DOM, THEN add the new items my element sits atop into the ele.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge, you could make the elements scrollable, you just have to make sure they are over the div.

Comment: Not so! I just watch for mousemove events on the window. See Kir's answer

Comment: Well, I would say yours was much better than his, or mine I'll admit, I was just saying it could be accomplished. :)